# CORS Error 405 method not allowed with response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: php, vuejs2, lumen

I've been trying using axios from Vue calling to my API in lumen but it sends options method in place of post because of CORS.

Here is my request details

General

```
Request URL: http://192.168.1.100/lv_api/code/login

Request Method: OPTIONS

Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

Remote Address: 192.168.1.100:80

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-
Requested-With

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.1.100:8000

Allow: POST

Cache-Control: no-cache, private

Connection: close

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Date: Wed, 03 Oct 2018 06:22:56 GMT

Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type

Access-Control-Request-Method: POST

Connection: keep-alive

Host: 192.168.1.100

Origin: http://192.168.1.100:8000

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

Tried setting headers but I am not sure about the proper values to be set for the issue.

If I create a method for Options request in my API it works fine but that's not the proper solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the first link of this [google search](https://www.google.it/search?q=enable+cors+php+lumen&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIT763IT763&oq=enable+cors+php+lumen&aqs=chrome..69i57.5416j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved the issue just by adding following lines in my api code

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your origin');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age:86400');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token,  Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can install spatie/laravel-cors for resolve this issue